# How to display name starting from 'z' by using BETWEEN cmd only?

Tags: sql, mysql

[used BETWEEN optr with range 'a' and 'z'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00tfM.png)

i want to get all the name by using BETWEEN operator only
but as you can see BETWEEN optr only include lower_range(a) and not upper_range(z) , but i also want name starting from character 'z'. can we get it??
note:we can only use BETWEEN optr.
You can look into the picture.

Comment: why do you want to use BETWEEN?

Comment: comparing a whole string to a single character returns expected result - change to test first character only. and to test by case use ascii code. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/string-functions.html https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: `between 'a' and 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'`, where the number of z's should be the same as the column length.

Answer (score 1):

if you can change also `name` column :

```
select * from sample1 where substring(name, 1, 1) between 'a' AND 'z'
```

**if you have many records, using rpad my degrade performance**

Comment: an expression like rpad('z', CONSTANT, 'z') will be evaluated only once, it's not rpad('z', length(name), 'z').

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

As second argument of the BETWEEN, uses the next character after z which is chr(ascii('z')+1) ("{") or use rpad('z',**length_of_name_column**, 'z').

Comment: using `{` would include rows where name was just `{`.  using rpad would exclude some things starting with z (e.g. `z{`).

Comment: they should not use BETWEEN for this. but if the assignment requires it they should do `LEFT(NAME,1) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z'`